# VSTO OUtlook 2007 deployment for all userr

Tags: deployment, outlook, vsto, installshield

I am using Installshield for deploying VSTO 2007 Outlook plugin to all users.  By default Office 2007 supports plugin deployment to current user only.  I come across the follwing link which describes it http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mshneer/archive/2008/04/24/deploying-your-vsto-add-in-to-all-users-part-iii.aspx

A hotfix http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976811 is available but it is not redstributable.

Is there any easiest way available specially for  Installshield.

Thanks,
Vinit

Answer (score 0):

Change the registry path from **HKEY_CURRENT_USER** to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE** in your setup project