# Deploy Document Level Customization With InstallShield or Deploy Files to Specified Folder with ClickOnce

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, vsto, clickonce, installshield

I am working on VSTO add-ins for excel and document level customizations.  They will be used on computers with several users (10 or so each).  By intention, we do want common database and report files on a server folder, instead we want all 10 users to be able to access a local database and reports (local to computer).  Right now I am doing this by a two step install.

First an InstallShield project unpacts all the ClickOnce files, default templates, and database files to `c:\LIMSersTestUnit` .  "Running the application when finished" runs the SetUp.exe from the ClickOnce file.  I am not having user use problems, perhaps because everything is launched from within a main document level customization.  IE I've used this method and had multiple users login and successfully use the program.  My problem is that in deploying this it has been cumbersome to rely on users to do this successfully.  My first stab was to just include everything in a zip file and tell them to unzip it into the correct directory, but that was a disaster.

I would like to combine this into one install if possible.  I understand that a folder of files can be included [with the VSTO project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy0fky2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) but this is put into a user specific folder.  I have not been able to figure out how to change this output path relative to root.  I'm still doing a lot of Googling on this, but I'm not even sure if it's possible.

On the flip side, I've not been able to get InstallShield to properly install the document level customization.  I've been trying to find an example of this online and so far I have failed.  I've tried including the manfests from the ClickOnce publication, along with the primary outputs of the VSTO project, but I've gotten no where.  I'm currently examining the registry and files created by the ClickOnce install to try and clone it.  It does a lot more on the security side of things than I realized.  I tried changing the registry path for the Excel Add-in to under [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647522/vsto-outlook-2007-deployment-for-all-userr), but that so far hasn't helped.

So my distilled questions are: 
Can I deploy files to a folder based on root path with ClickOnce? If so how?
Is there an obvious way or example of how to deploy a VSTO with InstallShield? I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsto/ff937654.aspx) but I haven't been able to get it work.  I am still working that end though.  If anyone knows of a better guide, please let me know.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are asking for, but it is possible to add file to application folder with click once application. See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926111/want-to-distribute-pdf-file-with-my-visual-basic-project-during-deploying/15928418#15928418

Comment: Nope, I don't want to add I file to the application folder.  As I mentioned, I knew how to do this.  The problem is that the application folder is going to go into a user specific folder, and I want to be able share the files locally.  I'm not sure if I will have to do the work to do a full multi-user install (from what I've read that seems quite difficult and not possible from ClickOnce).  Instead I just want to extract shared files relative to root (C:\example).

Comment: Doesn't matter, I even got notification for your comment despite that. It may not be the cleanest solution, but why don't you first put the file in the default VSTO folder and then the first time program runs move it to the directory you want (C:\example). Just don't forget that hard drvies can be renamed...